# Is it possible to rotate YouTube videos while watching on desktop PC?

Tags: firefox, video, youtube

Nowadays many people use mobile devices to watch videos on YouTube, so the creators of some videos began to adapt their videos to such devices, turning them 90 degrees counterclockwise ([random example from YouTube - some girl is dancing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3C_93n0eXwA)). This makes it convenient to view in case where you can easily rotate the device 90 degrees.

But how to watch such videos on a regular desktop, with a monitor fixed in one position? Maybe there are any plug-ins or viewers for such streaming video that allow you to easily rotate the video while watching? This task should not be resource-consuming - you just need to swap the horizontal and vertical axis.

(if it's important - I use Firefox to watch YouTube, but I'm willing to consider using a different browser if it's necessary)

Comment: Try the extension [Rotate Youtube Video](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/rotate-youtube-video/).

Comment: @harrymc, Thank you very much, it works! I didn't even think it would be so easy! Please post your comment as an answer, I really want to vote up for it and accept.

Comment: Done as requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the extension [Rotate Youtube Video](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/rotate-youtube-video/):

> a toolbar button for easier rotate youtube video

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Free Chrome Extension Smuuvr for desktop to rotate YouTube videos at any 45 or 90 degree angle (while watching them) [Rotate Videos with: Smuuvr - The Amazing Website Improver](https://smuuvr.com)

It also hides banner ads and has dark mode which is nice to have all in one add-on

Answer (score 0):

You can hack to unhide the hidden rotate buttons in YouTube editor. Here is how to do:

1. On your YouTube channel, click **YOUTUBE STUDIO** and it jump you to channel dashboard;
   Click on **Videos**, on the video you like to rotate, click **Details** and it jumps to the video details page;
2. Click on **Editor** > **ADD BLUR**;
3. Find the *Trim* button, right click on it and choose **Insepct eliment**. This will open a new panel where you’ll see some code. Find the section that says ‘**hidden=true**’; double click the word ‘**hidden**’, delete it and press **Enter**. Then the rotate button will appear beside the **Trim** button;
4. Close the panel and click the rotate button to rotate YouTube video;
   [image]

Comment: Don't know if this is serious or troll. Anyway now that Youtube Studio changed unrecognizably, I cant verify it. Though it does seem odd. Youtube Studio sounds like something that whould only contain *your own* videos.